# domino 901 FP3 and JVM SR16 FP3 upgrade causing issues with javascript written in HTML attributes of a field

Tags: javascript, html, lotus-domino

We have our application hosted on Domino server. Recently after **domino 901 FP3** and **JVM SR16 FP3** upgrade on the server there has been an issue.

There is a Dialog list field with option "Yes" and "No" (set to "No" by default). Earlier on change of this field value from "No" to "Yes", a few more fields were loading. But now after the upgrade, the form just submits.

```
"class=\" iform \" onChange =\"this.form.submit();\"  OnFocus=\"dispsendhelp(this);\" onblur = \"window.status = ' ' ;\""
```

This is the value given in the HTML attributes of the field.

It would be helpful if there is any alternate for this code in the HTML attributes that would make the application work like before.

Comment: Have you tried with the latest 9.0.1 FP3 interim fix (IF3)? See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21657963

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information. Could you please let me know what issues this fixpack will address?